# What is the best way to use OR in python regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-2.x

I'm doing an homework on regex and having some difficulties with `OR`.
Given the following strings:

```
avc7fsrd5vcc12vfscsrwt1qw7eetrs&fsrsy
```

> should return t1 s

```
fdjhads jhf&5672t3zcxvb,m654godjhfjdyeuyr123jfjjdjfjdfj77djsfhdjhfdsf99
```

> should return t3 go 123 77

The first part is to extract t with some number and then extract s or go depending on what comes first. If its go, then we need to extract two numbers afterward, otherwise stop.

This is the regex I'm using

```
 '(t[0-9]).*?(go).*?([0-9]+).*?([0-9]+)|(t[0-9]).*?(s)'
```

but it doesn't work when I add an s to the second string and extracts go instead of s.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `then we need to extract two numbers afterward` after _what_?

Comment: For the second sample `t3...go...123...77` because 654 is before `go`

Answer (score 1):

Its fairly simple. The first alternation has priority over the second.
Just make sure there is no `s` before go.

`(t[0-9])[^s]*?(go).*?([0-9]+).*?([0-9]+)|(t[0-9]).*?(s)`

[Formatted and tested:](http://www.regexformat.com)

```
    ( t [0-9] )                   # (1)
    [^s]*? 
    ( go )                        # (2)
    .*? 
    ( [0-9]+ )                    # (3)
    .*? 
    ( [0-9]+ )                    # (4)
 |  
    ( t [0-9] )                   # (5)
    .*? 
    ( s )                         # (6)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm fairly new to regex. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Read about [**`regex`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) here:

```
print re.findall(r'(t\d+).*?(s|go)\D*(\d*)\D*(\d*)', s)
```

Output:

```
[('t3', 'go', '123', '77')]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the regex you need:

```
                      (t\d+).*?(go|s)\D*?(\d*)\D*?(\d*)
```

It works as per your requirement if i understood you question properly.

Demo for 1st match:
http://regexr.com/3coi0

Demo for 2nd match
:
http://regexr.com/3coht

For more help in understanding advance regex, i'd refer you to read 
https://www.talentcookie.com/2015/07/lets-practice-regular-expression
https://www.talentcookie.com/2016/01/some-useful-regular-expression-terminologies/