# String searching - Python

Tags: python

I need to be able to check if a string contains a number of letters and integers, and if possible how to split a string into three separate parts based off user input, any ideas? 
any help is useful thanks

Comment: Please give some examples of the data you want to work with and how you want it to be split up.

Comment: There's no question other than "any ideas?" in your question...

Comment: *"any ideas?"* - write some code? Read a tutorial? Do some thinking?

Comment: `if 'x' in mystring: do_something()`

Comment: Consider this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35282775/what-is-the-best-way-to-use-or-in-python-regex

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is to use regex. You can filter out the numbers only

```
import re
str1=aas30dsa20
str2=re.sub("\D", "", str1)
'3020'
```

You can then search for the result in the original string

```
start=str1.index(str2)
end=len(str1)
```

Finally filter it with

```
originalStr[start:end]
```